# Force Sensitive Droids/Cyborgs

Tags: star-wars, the-force, droids, cyborg

Is it possible for a Droid or a Cyborg to be sensitive to the force and ultimately train to become a Jedi/Sith?

I was thinking General Grievous might be but I can't remember how he got his lightsabers. Are there any other examples in the canon?

Comment: Also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8081/31936

Comment: Re: Grievous http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64248/31936

Comment: I didn't think to google "machines". Sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm just marking as duplicate since the answers to your question exist and you don't need to wait for new ones. For your future reference, I found these questions by [searching](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=) the keywords in your question on this site (e.g. `[star-wars] Force droid is:question` and `[star-wars] Force Grievous is:question`).

Comment: Wrong duplicate! Should be [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/are-there-any-jedi-or-sith-droids?lq=1).

Comment: I wouldn't say its the wrong duplicate, I would say there is more than one possible answer available to mark it a duplicate of...

Comment: The idea of Skippy has changed my life. Just not sure if it is positive or negative...