# Can droids be force-sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, droids

In the *Star Wars* universe can droids be Force-sensitive? Were there any droids that could use Force powers?

Is it possible in the *Star Wars* universe for a droid to become Force-sensitive?

What about androids if not droids? I think biological material is needed.

Comment: That's not a duplicate for sure!

Comment: The previous question [asking about cyborgs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106131/force-sensitive-droids-cyborgs?rq=1) was closed as a duplicate of the question linked above. Sorry.